# UITableview Changes Y position when returned from previous view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am having a view that contains a **Navigation bar**, A **UISegmentedController** with two segment "A" and "B". By default it has "A" selected, beside which a `tableview` is being displayed. Now on clicking "B" `tableview` will increase its y position by 20 and height is also calculated accordingly and `searchBar` will be displayed.

If again user select "A" then search bar will be hidden and `tableview` y position will be decreased by 20 and height is also calculated accordingly. It works fine when are switching between different segment. Now issue arises when user user has selected "A" segment and now If I am navigating to another view and returning back then table view's Y position is increased by 20.

My `viewWillAppear` doesnt contain any code, Moreover I haven't implemented any view related methods except `viewWillAppear`. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewDidLoad")

    //Calling function that will insert static data to tableview
    self.settingStaticData()
    //Calling function that would customize Search bar
    self.customizingSearchBar()

    //For detecting whether searching is enabled or not
    boolisSearching = false
    //By setting default selected segment value to 0
    intSelectedSegmentId = 0;
    self.displayRequestview() 
}

func displayRequestview(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.searchBar?.hidden = true
        self.tblSuggestions?.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,(self.tblSuggestions?.frame.size.width)!,(self.tblSuggestions?.frame.size.height)!+44.0)
        print("in Request View Height \((self.tblSuggestions?.frame.size.height)!)")

    }
    //Reloading data
    self.tblSuggestions?.reloadData()
    self.tblSuggestions?.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated:true)
}


func displaySuggestionView(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.searchBar?.hidden = false
       self.tblSuggestions?.frame = CGRectMake(0,44.0,(self.tblSuggestions?.frame.size.width)!,(self.tblSuggestions?.frame.size.height)!-44.0)
        //print("After Height \(self.tblSuggestions?.frame.size.height)")
    }
    //Reloading data
    self.tblSuggestions?.reloadData()
    self.tblSuggestions?.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated:true)

}
@IBAction func segmentValueChanged(sender: AnyObject){

    let segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = sender as! UISegmentedControl
    if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        print("Height Before Change  \((tblSuggestions?.superview?.bounds.height)!)")
        intSelectedSegmentId = 0
        displayRequestview()
    }
    else if(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
    {
        intSelectedSegmentId = 1
        displaySuggestionView()
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: I think your code to increase size is getting called when you navigating. post necessary code if you not identify.

Comment: A screen shot would help us more to check the problem.

Comment: @thanks for your valuable response. Please have a look into my code.

Comment: Hi. Is autolayout enabled in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Go to XIB or Storyboard file

Check 'Top Bar' & 'Status Bar' settings for both views A & B.

20 points are being added/removed because of status bar.

Hope it will resolve.

Comment: A and B view is not a different view but managed within single view which contains Search bar and tableview. When user selects "A" then searchbar gets hidden y position of table view decreases by 20. And in case user select "B" then search bar becomes visible and tableview moves down by 20.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input Shahab. But its not working.